# CakePHP passing root dir to javascript

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am not quite sure how to achieve passing the relative project root directory to a javascript file.
Purpose of having this is to call an ajax function that should use relative paths to the root dir.

However, one ugly method would be to store the dir in the meta fields of the HTML header, but I really want to avoid this.

Any theoretical suggestion?

Are there any kind of Javascript helper in version 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use router class for that

Use below namespace

```
use Cake\Routing\Router;
```

Then in your ajax URL you can use below code

```
url:'<?php echo Router::url(['controller' => 'YourController', 'action' => 'Method']); ?>',
```

Comment: This is only possible if the javascript is inside your view or not? Otherwise, how should it be possible to use PHP code inside your javascript? For me that sounds like a security risk

Comment: You would put something like this, presumably wrapped in `<script>` tags, in the view, or the layout if you needed it everywhere. Any other JavaScript that you have would then be able to reference the variable.